# how to use window.location to call a page method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to hit my server side method in my asp.net app. Why is this not working? btw I cant use jquery in this case.

server:

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
        public static string HelloWorld()
        {
            //do something
        }
```

client

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = "http://localhost//default.aspx/HelloWorld";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript works for me. Looks like you have an extra / between localhost and default.aspx. Perhaps you mean:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost/default.aspx/HelloWorld";
```

I'd try to log something on the server side, and go to that location directly to see if the server is setup correctly.

Comment: which part is not working for you? if you are in firebug/chrome in a javascript console and you type the window.location... does that work? Or are you going to the location, and get the asp.net to log anything?